# Dealing with spaces in directory names in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, directory

Disclaimer: I am very new to Bash scripting (and Linux in general), so forgive me for a stupid question.

A friend of mine gave me a script which makes a backup copy of certain files onto Dropbox. Here's the code in full:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
tarname='backup-'$DATE'.tar.gz'

cd ~/
directoriesToBack='.bashrc Desktop/School/ Desktop/Research\ Project'

tar -X ~/Desktop/My\ Programs/scripts/crons/exclude.txt -zcvf $tarname $directoriesToBack

mv $tarname ~/Dropbox
```

The variable `directoriesToBack` obviously contains the directories to be copied. Exclude.txt is a text file of files which are not to be backed up.

If I try to run this script, I get an error because of `Desktop/Research Project`: my computer looks for the directory `Desktop/Research` instead. I've tried to use double quotes instead of single quotes, and to replace `\` with an ordinary space, but these tries didn't work. Does anyone know how I can make a backup of a directory with spaces in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do this with strings. It will not work and it will cause pain. See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for various details and discussion.

Use an array instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
tarname=backup-$DATE.tar.gz

cd ~/
directoriesToBack=(.bashrc Desktop/School "Desktop/Research Project")

tar -X ~/Desktop/My\ Programs/scripts/crons/exclude.txt -zcvf "$tarname" "${directoriesToBack[@]}"
```

I also fixed the quoting of variables/etc. and used `$()` instead of backticks for the date command execution (as `$()` can be nested and generally has better semantics and behaviour).

Comment: Your code unfortunately produced the error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Ah, true, `/bin/sh` doesn't do arrays. Needs `bash` or other shell. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the script and show the EXACT error message.  I suspect that what is going wrong is not what you think it is.  I suspect that the envar directoriesToBack is not what you think it is.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

cd Desktop/"Research Project" (With Quotation marks)

You'll find that a lot of code in many languages use Quotes to signify a space.

Comment: This code still produces an error message: `tar: Desktop/"Research: Cannot stat: No such file or directory; tar: Desktop/"Research: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`